# Huawei Drmcheck: App rejected not purchased

Tags: java, android, huawei-developers

I have added the Huawei DrmCheck to my app. I did it like in this example [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-paidapps-check-0000001073193403).

Huawei rejected my app with: Your App prompts that the account has not purchased it, after launched via a Huawei ID....

I am not surprised now, because Huawei will not have purchased the app from the Store.
How can I work around this problem?

Thanks